# Xcode 8 Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm trying to fix this issue for hours, but it still persists. Tried everything on the forums, nothing helped.
I'm using Cocoapods latest version 1.2.0.beta.1
When I try to build the project, it gives me this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just deleted cocoapods beta version and installed the normal one.

Answer (score 11):

For me (Xcode 9) `pod install` on its own did not fix it.
Tried it with:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

And the error disappeared.

You might also want to consider deleting the derived data folders for this project. The location of DerivedData is in your error log.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I did to remove this error. Please try with below:

> 1. Click on main project file.
> 2. Goto the Build Phases.
> 3. Click on run Script and delete any given path in it so that it does not try to find some framework that has been deleted by you.

I had this problem when I used to check the crash Analytics with the different frameworks like "Test Fairy".

Hope this works. :)

Comment: Thank you! Was removing firebase from an old app and this was it

Answer (score 7):

Install the pods once again and run the project. Using command:

```
pod install
```

Comment: just applied  , still failed to build

Answer (score 2):

My solution was restarting my computer. Xcode must have got into a bad state that restarting Xcode itself was not enough to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did when I got this:

1. Used this site to completely remove All Versions of cocoapods:
   https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine
2. Re-installed current stable version of cocoapods (v1.1.1 for me)
3. Deleted podlock and pods directory
4. Deleted old .xcworkspace file (this was key for me).
5. Did "pod install"
6. Opened xcode and cleaned project and deleted derivedData.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Carthage`, the reason these errors came out was because I changed the target iOS version from iOS 10 to iOS 9, I solved this problem by running `carthage update` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated my pods again and It started working.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the Terminal and find your file and type in "pod install", that will solve the problem.

Comment: This solution has already been posted. Also, one-liners are generally not considered very good answers.