# iOS Swift No Such File or Directory In Debug-iphoneos

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

Somebody please save me.

This is the error I'm getting. I've tried cleaning, doing a build clean, pod installs and updates. I have not found a solution.

Shell Script Invocation Error Group
/Users/arthuraraujo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Anti-Social_Club-gizjofrkxroutxezxlbuadlvpwbo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Anti-Social: No such file or directory

Comment: Try deleting derived data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have similar issues in the past and doing the following work for me. Hope your problem is same as mine:

1. Close xCode
2. Go to this folder Group
   /Users/arthuraraujo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Anti-Social_Club-gizjofrkxroutxezxlbuadlvpwbo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/
   and delete Anti-Social.
3. Restart xCode, clean & build.

Comment: I still get this error when doing that, and deleting DerivedData, and restarting XCode, and after cleaning, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to really tell you the solution with just the information provided.  However, the first thing I would try is deleting the derived data, as CodeBender stated.  You should also look at your search paths in your project's building settings to make sure your pods are correct/ connecting your pods files to your project.

Comment: I have also had to add '${PODS_ROOT}/' (without the single quotes) to my Header search paths with recursive option; for header files to be found when stating 'use_frameworks!' in my Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of:
[Xcode 8 Shell Script Invocation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329247/xcode-8-shell-script-invocation-error/40740120#40740120)

Here is what I did when I got this:

1. Used this site to completely remove All Versions of cocoapods:
   https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine
2. Re-installed current stable version of cocoapods (v1.1.1 for me)
3. Deleted podlock and pods directory
4. Deleted old .xcworkspace file (this was key for me).
5. Did "pod install"
6. Opened xcode and cleaned project and deleted derivedData.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your build phases and remove libReact.a from the linked libraries.

Then add libReact.a but select this one:

> libReact.a from 'React' target in 'Pods' project